# how do i get into the data folders of minecraft windows 10 edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have seen questions like this, but all relate to either the operating system itself or the java version of minecraft. I tried looking for the files myself, but I never figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The file folders for the Windows 10 edition of Minecraft are in: C:\User\Name Of User\AppData\Local\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang

In there you will find several folders containing the data of Minecraft Windows 10 Edition. You will specifically find the folders for your worlds, your resource packs, etc. I have done this several times. I first learned this from http://mcpedl.com/install-maps-minecraft-windows-10-edition/